# Convert a string column to number in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding

I'm trying to convert a column in my DataFrame to numbers. The input is email domains extracted from email addresses. Sample:

```
>>> data['emailDomain']
0                         [gmail]
1                         [gmail]
2                         [gmail]
3                           [aol]
4                         [yahoo]
5                         [yahoo]
```

I want to create a new column where if the domain is `gmail` or `aol`, the column entry would be a `1` and `0` otherwise.
I created a method which goes like this:

```
def convertToNumber(row):
    try:
        if row['emailDomain'] == '[gmail]':
            return 1
        elif row['emailDomain'] == '[aol]':
            return 1
        elif row['emailDomain'] == '[outlook]':
            return 1
        elif row['emailDomain'] == '[hotmail]':
            return 1
        elif row['emailDomain'] == '[yahoo]':
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    except TypeError:
        print("TypeError")
```

and used it like:

```
data['validEmailDomain'] = data.apply(convertToNumber, axis=1)
```

However, my output column is `0` even when I know there are gmail and aol emails present in the input column. 
Any idea what could be going wrong?

Also, I think this usage of conditional statements might not be the most efficient way to tackle this problem. Is there any other approach to getting this done?

Comment: Are you sure your series is made of strings. It appears they might be lists...

Comment: how do you do the extraction?

Comment: @MaartenFabré `x = re.findall('(?<=@)[^.]+(?=\.)', row['email'])
        return x` like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas-series-isin)

```
providers = {'gmail', 'aol', 'yahoo','hotmail', 'outlook'}
data['emailDomain'].isin(providers)
```

## searching the provider

instead of applying a `re` to each email in each row, you can use the [`Series.str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) methods to do it on a columns at a time

```
pattern2 = '(?<=@)([^.]+)(?=\.)'
df['email'].str.extract(pattern2, expand=False)
```

so this becomes something like this:

```
pattern2 = '(?<=@)([^.]+)(?=\.)'
providers = {'gmail', 'aol', 'yahoo','hotmail', 'outlook'}
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'email': ['test.1@gmail.com', 'test.2@aol.com', 'test3@something.eu']})

provider_serie = df['email'].str.extract(pattern2, expand=False)
```

> ```
> 0        gmail
> 1          aol
> 2    something
> Name: email, dtype: object
> ```

```
interested_providers = df['email'].str.extract(pattern2, expand=False).isin(providers)
```

> ```
> 0     True
> 1     True
> 2    False
> Name: email, dtype: bool
> ```

If you really want `0`s and `1`s, you can add a `.astype(int)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, there was some issue with the format of the data I extracted using `re`. Using str.extract worked

Answer (score 0):

You could sum up the occurence checks of every Provider via list comprehensions and write the resulting list into `data['validEmailDomain']`:

```
providers = ['gmail', 'aol', 'outlook', 'hotmail', 'yahoo']
data['validEmailDomain'] = [np.sum([p in e for p in providers]) for e in data['emailDomain'].values]
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, it might be good to include a description of how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would work if your series contained strings. As such, they likely contain lists, in which case you need to extract the first element.

I would also utilise `pd.Series.map` instead of using any row-wise logic. Below is a complete example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'emailDomain': [['gmail'], ['gmail'], ['gmail'], ['aol'],
                                   ['yahoo'], ['yahoo'], ['else']]})

domains = {'gmail', 'aol', 'outlook', 'hotmail', 'yahoo'}

df['validEmailDomain'] = df['emailDomain'].map(lambda x: x[0]).isin(domains)\
                                          .astype(int)

print(df)

#   emailDomain  validEmailDomain
# 0     [gmail]                 1
# 1     [gmail]                 1
# 2     [gmail]                 1
# 3       [aol]                 1
# 4     [yahoo]                 1
# 5     [yahoo]                 1
# 6      [else]                 0
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__` while following this approach. And you're right about containing a list.

Comment: @MahboobMustafa, Can't reproduce your error. Clearly something is wrong with your data, but you need to provide an example *in the same way I have in my question* for me to advise.